# C++ - .h and .cpp

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header, implementation

If I have a `.h` file that contains the following for example:

```
class A
{
...
}
```

Notice that there is no customized constructor here.

Now, in the .cpp file, can I write the following:

```
A
{
...
}
```

In other words, is it ok *not* to use a *constructor* after the class name as follows?

```
A::A()
{
...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what are you planning to write in `A{...}`? It is not a valid synatx.

Comment: `A{...}` is not valid, provided that it's an accidentally valid macro !!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes You Can.If i understood your question correctly.

HEADER FILE

```
#include < iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
        A();
        void func();
};
```

CPP FILE

```
#include "h.hpp"

using namespace std;

A::A(){cout << "Constructor" << endl;}

int main(){
A a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how you interpreted the question as to come to 'yes' as the answer. As I interpreted it, it's very much 'no'.

Comment: This doesn't even come *close* to an answer. You at least need some explanation of *why* the answer is yes.

Comment: @Cody and ildjam : Please find the code according to my understading of the question.

Comment: @OP : Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: @ALL: Its high time that SO must force people who down-vote irresponsibly to comment on why they have down voted. It really helps to improve an answer with right comments but just down-voting is really a stupid and childish behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is whether or not you can use A{} to define a constructor, no, you need to use A::A(){...} syntax for the constructor if you are defining it in the cpp file.

If you are asking if you don't need a constructor, no, you don't necessarily need one, the compiler will supply you with a default.

I should say that if you are doing the constructor in the class definition you can use A(){...}, such as

```
class A
{
public:
  A(){}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to your question is "No". But it's kind of a confusing question. The syntax you propose for the contents of the .cpp file is demonstrably uncompilable.

Answer (score 0):

*is it ok not to use a constructor after the class name*

As classes get longer and more complicated, mixing the definition and the implementation details makes the class harder to manage and work with.

Traditionally, the class definition is put in a header file of the same name as the class, and the member functions defined outside of the class are put in a .cpp file of the same name as the class.

Answer (score 0):

No. Once you've defined class A like that, the compiler expects `A` to start one of

```
A MyObject;
A MyOtherObject = { /* initial values */ }; // C style since there's no ctor
A MyFunction();
A MyFunction() { return MyObject; }
```

or perhaps a variation like

```
A* MyPointer;
A& MyReferemce = MyObject;
```

As you see, the compiler expects you declare something after `A`. But you have `A {`. That's just not right: you started a declaration, but you never named what you're declaring.